# How do life cycle hooks methods get executed in Angular when Typescript basically transpiles to Javascript which has no concept of Interfaces?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example, the hook ngOnit() makes use of the Onit interface, in the componentName.component.ts file. When we run our app using ng serve --open, why does the code inside ngOnit() {...} get executed despite of the fact that Typescript transpiles to javascript in the end(javascript does not know what interface is)

P.S. I am new to Angular and Typescript, I just have a basic Javascript understanding, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: How does Typescript work at all, if it only compiles to Javascript?

Comment: `ngOnInit` will perfectly work without implementing any interface. `Angular instead inspects directive and component classes and calls the hook methods if they are defined. Angular finds and calls methods like ngOnInit(), with or without the interfaces.` See: [https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)